# Потребление памяти DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с потреблением памяти DataTable (использую SQLite).
При 500 000 записей программа потребляет ~340 МБ. Виртуализация DataGrid включена.

В интернете находил ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WebControls/ ), что нужно использовать виртуализацию данных, но возникла проблема:
все классы рассчитаны на фиксированное кол-во столбцов, а в процессе работы программы пользователю потребуется добавлять/удалять столбцы.

```
class ExampleTable
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public int code { get; set; }
     public string product { get; set; }
     public string type { get; set; }
}
...
ObservableCollection<ExampleTable> tbl = new ObservableCollection<ExampleTable>();
...
```

Выше класс для реализации столбцов (№, Код, Товар, Тип).
Что можно сделать, чтобы в классе реализовать произвольное кол-во столбцов?
Или посоветуйте другое решение, как сделать виртуализацию данных. Спасибо.

Comment: Какая цель таких операций?  Для работы с огромными данными придумали СУБД, и отображают/рендерят лишь их малую часть, или бьют "простыню" на приемлемые куски/периоды.

Comment: Добавил, что использую SQLite. Суть вопроса именно в том, как правильно разбить это на куски (это и есть виртуализация данных).

Comment: Через что читаете? Обычно используется IDataReader, если да - делайте холостое чтение.

Comment: А лучше - уменьшайте период в выборке, сделайте sql-нумерацию, выбирайте диапазон уже, разбейте по-дням, по-часам. Думаю 500 000 записей никто просматривать не будет.

Comment: Читаю через SQLiteDataAdapter. А насчёт выборки спасибо, попробую сделать так.

Comment: Вот:  `DataAdapter.Fill (DataTable[], IDataReader, Int32 from, Int32 max)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/59wzthcw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx все перезагрузки `Fill` поддерживают взятие куска

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь создал переменные с текущим индексом и кол-во строк в таблице. Когда DataGrid прокрутится до конца, плюсую к текущему индексу нужно кол-во строк и заполняю таблицу (и наоборот для прокрутки вверх), а стартовое значение начинается с предыдущего индекса.

Comment: У вас одновременно используется и `System.Data.DataTable` и коллекция классов модели?

Comment: В `DataTable` можно свободно добавлять/удалять колонки на ходу. Тогда всю работу нужно делать с ним, не используя класс модели.

Comment: Используется только DataTable, коллекция не используется, я просто думал, как можно обработать большое кол-во данных.   А вся проблема заключается в том, что с большими данными в одной таблице я не работал, поэтому проблема еще актуальна. Идея с виртуализацией пришла отсюда: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WebControls/ но я так и не понял, как реализовать коллекцию с произвольным количеством стоблцов. В примере на CodeProject даже 2 млн записей прокручивается быстро и потребляет всего 25 МБ.